# How to spellcheck in an SWT application

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp, spell-checking

I have an eclipse plugin RCP application and I would like to use a spell checker on a SWT browser widget. Just checking to see if anyone knows how to implement this or if there is something built in.

Comment: Eclipse has a spellcheck embedded. It basically just checks your words (in comments) against a list of words it stores somewhere.

Comment: so how do i use this spell checker in my application. How do I instantiate it.

Comment: I am not sure you want to do spell check in the browser or in a text editor? To do spell check on the browser, may you could execute spell check java script on browser.

Comment: that is the browser widget that I have text in. I want to check the spelling of it.

Comment: @Will : Did you find any answers to your question... actually i need to know exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@tm.sauron This was quite a long time ago so I had to look through an old project. If I remember correctly I ended up creating my own. I created a Dialog that would open when I clicked the spell check icon in my rich text editor. I will paste the code to the dialog and actual spell checker class. Hope you can see what I am doing and figure it out.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.eclipse.epf.richtext.IRichText;
import org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.FocusAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.FocusEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.KeyAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.KeyEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.List;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;

public class SpellCheckerDialog extends BaseDialog {

    private SpellChecker spellChecker;
    private Queue<String> misspelledWords = new LinkedList<String>();
    private Text wrongWord;
    private List suggestedWords;
    private Button ignoreButton;
    private Button changeButton;
    private IgnoreButtonListener ignoreButtonListener = new IgnoreButtonListener();
    private ChangeButtonListener changeButtonListener = new ChangeButtonListener();
    private ModifiedChangeButtonListener modifiedChangeButtonListener = new ModifiedChangeButtonListener();
    private ModifiedIgnoreButtonListener modifiedIgnoreButtonListener = new ModifiedIgnoreButtonListener();
    private String oldWrongWord;
    private int currentWord = 1;
    private int totalWords;
    private IRichText richText;
    private String noHTMLString;

    public SpellCheckerDialog(Shell parent, IRichText richText) {
        super(parent);
        setShellStyle(SWT.DIALOG_TRIM | SWT.MODELESS | getDefaultOrientation());

        this.richText = richText;

        if (richText != null) {
            /* Instantiate spell checker */
            try {
                spellChecker = new SpellChecker();
                findMisspelledWords();
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                MessageDialog.openInformation(Display.getDefault().getActiveShell(), "Dictionary file for rich text editor not found", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                MessageDialog.openInformation(Display.getDefault().getActiveShell(), "Dictionary file for rich text editor not found", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent) {
        Composite composite = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);
        composite.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));
        composite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

        /* Not in dictionary label */
        new Label(composite, SWT.NONE).setText("Not in Dictionary:");
        new Label(composite, SWT.NONE);

        /* Current Misspelled Word */
        wrongWord = new Text(composite, SWT.MULTI | SWT.BORDER | SWT.WRAP | SWT.V_SCROLL);
        GridData gd = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
        gd.heightHint = 75;
        gd.minimumHeight = 75;
        wrongWord.setLayoutData(gd);
        wrongWord.addKeyListener(new WrongWordKeyListener());
        wrongWord.addFocusListener(new WrongWordFocusListener());

        /* Ignore Button Actions */
        GridData buttonCompositeGridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, false, true);
        buttonCompositeGridData.widthHint = 125;
        Composite topButtonActionsComposite = new Composite(composite, SWT.NONE);
        topButtonActionsComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        topButtonActionsComposite.setLayoutData(buttonCompositeGridData);
        ignoreButton = new Button(topButtonActionsComposite, SWT.PUSH);
        ignoreButton.setText("Ignore");
        ignoreButton.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false));
        ignoreButton.addSelectionListener(ignoreButtonListener);

        /* Suggestions label */
        new Label(composite, SWT.NONE).setText("Suggestions:");
        new Label(composite, SWT.NONE);

        /* Suggested Words */
        suggestedWords = new List(composite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.SINGLE);
        suggestedWords.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

        /* Change Button Actions */
        Composite bottomButtonActionsComposite = new Composite(composite, SWT.NONE);
        bottomButtonActionsComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        bottomButtonActionsComposite.setLayoutData(buttonCompositeGridData);
        changeButton = new Button(bottomButtonActionsComposite, SWT.PUSH);
        changeButton.setText("Change");
        changeButton.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false));
        changeButton.addSelectionListener(changeButtonListener);

        startSpellChecking();
        return composite;
    }

    private void startSpellChecking() {
        if (!misspelledWords.isEmpty()) {
            super.getShell().setText("Spell Checker (" + currentWord + "/" + totalWords + ")");
            String firstWord = misspelledWords.poll();
            HashMap<Integer, String> suggestions = spellChecker.suggestions(firstWord);

            /* get order of suggestions */
            java.util.List<Integer> sortedKeys = asSortedList(suggestions.keySet());

            wrongWord.setText(firstWord);

            suggestedWords.removeAll();
            for (Integer i : sortedKeys) {
                suggestedWords.add(suggestions.get(i));
            }

            /* if there are no suggestions */
            if (suggestions.size() == 0) {
                suggestedWords.add("No Suggestions");
                changeButton.setEnabled(false);
            } else {
                changeButton.setEnabled(true);
            }

            suggestedWords.select(0);
            currentWord++;
        } else {
            MessageDialog.openInformation(Display.getDefault().getActiveShell(), "No Misspellings", "There were no more misspelled words found.");
            super.close();
        }
    }

    private void findMisspelledWords() {
        misspelledWords.clear();

        /* Get all words in textfield */
        String[] cleanWords = cleanText(richText.getText());
        for(String w:cleanWords){
            System.out.println(w);
        }

        for (String word : cleanWords) {
            if (!word.equals(" ") && !word.isEmpty()) {
                if (!spellChecker.isInDictionary(word)) {
                    misspelledWords.add(word);
                }
            }
        }
        totalWords = misspelledWords.size();
    }

    /**
     * removes html content, new line characters, white spaces at the beginning
     * or end of words, punctuation or non-letters, makes lowercase because that
     * is what the dictionary works with
     * 
     * @param text
     * @return
     */
    private String[] cleanText(String text) {
        /* Remove html */
        noHTMLString = text.replaceAll("\\<.*?>", "");
        noHTMLString = noHTMLString.replaceAll("&.*?;", "");
        if (noHTMLString.contains("<")) {
            int length = 0;
            while (noHTMLString.length() != length) {
                length = htmlTagRemoval(noHTMLString);
            }
            System.out.println("after manual removal noHTMLString: " + noHTMLString);
        }

        /* Remove New Lines */
        noHTMLString = noHTMLString.replaceAll("[\\t\\n\\r]", " ");

        String[] allWords = noHTMLString.split(" ");
        java.util.List<String> cleanedAllWords = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (String word : allWords) {
            /* remove white spaces */
            word = word.trim();
            /* remove non letters */
            if (!containsOnlyLetters(word)) {
                word = removeNonLetters(word);
            }
            cleanedAllWords.add(word);
        }

        /* Make all lowercase */
        for (int i = 0; i < cleanedAllWords.size(); i++) {
            cleanedAllWords.set(i, cleanedAllWords.get(i).toLowerCase());
        }

        return cleanedAllWords.toArray(new String[cleanedAllWords.size()]);
    }

    private int htmlTagRemoval(String string) {
        int i = 0;
        Integer start = null, end = null;
        for (i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
            if (string.toCharArray()[i] == '<') {
                start = i;
            }
            if (start != null && string.toCharArray()[i] == '>') {
                end = i;
                noHTMLString = string.replace(string.subSequence(start, end + 1), "");
                break;
            }
        }
        return i;
    }

    private boolean containsOnlyLetters(String s) {
        if (Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z]+", s)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private String removeNonLetters(String s) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i)) || s.charAt(i) == '\'') {
                sb = sb.append(s.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private class WrongWordKeyListener extends KeyAdapter {
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

            /*
             * Disable suggested words and change ignore button to undo button
             * and the change button listener
             */
            suggestedWords.setEnabled(false);

            ignoreButton.setEnabled(true);
            ignoreButton.setText("Undo Edit");
            ignoreButton.removeSelectionListener(ignoreButtonListener);
            ignoreButton.addSelectionListener(modifiedIgnoreButtonListener);

            changeButton.setEnabled(true);
            changeButton.removeSelectionListener(changeButtonListener);
            changeButton.addSelectionListener(modifiedChangeButtonListener);

            wrongWord.removeKeyListener(this);

        }
    }

    /**
     * This stors the old word incase the user wants to undo the edit later.
     * 
     * @author Will
     * 
     */
    private class WrongWordFocusListener extends FocusAdapter {
        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
            oldWrongWord = wrongWord.getText();
            super.focusGained(e);
        }
    }

    private class IgnoreButtonListener extends SelectionAdapter {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            // go to next word
            startSpellChecking();
        }
    }

    private class ChangeButtonListener extends SelectionAdapter {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            String newWord = suggestedWords.getSelection()[0];

            // change old word
            String correctedChanges = richText.getText().replace(wrongWord.getText(), newWord);
            richText.setText(correctedChanges);

            // next word
            startSpellChecking();

        }
    }

    /**
     * This is used when the user manually edits the misspelled word and changes
     * it
     * 
     * @author Will
     * 
     */
    private class ModifiedChangeButtonListener extends SelectionAdapter {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            String newWord = wrongWord.getText();

            // change old word
            String correctedChanges = richText.getText().replace(oldWrongWord, newWord);
            richText.setText(correctedChanges);

            ignoreButton.setText("Ignore");
            ignoreButton.removeSelectionListener(modifiedIgnoreButtonListener);
            ignoreButton.addSelectionListener(ignoreButtonListener);

            changeButton.removeSelectionListener(modifiedChangeButtonListener);
            changeButton.addSelectionListener(changeButtonListener);

            suggestedWords.setEnabled(true);

            wrongWord.addKeyListener(new WrongWordKeyListener());

            // next word
            startSpellChecking();

        }
    }

    /**
     * This is used when the user manually edits the misspelled word and wants
     * to undo changes
     * 
     * @author Will
     * 
     */
    private class ModifiedIgnoreButtonListener extends SelectionAdapter {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            /*
             * rename ignore button, fix listeners on both buttons, enable
             * suggested words, undo edit, add modify listener back
             */
            ignoreButton.setText("Ignore");
            ignoreButton.removeSelectionListener(modifiedIgnoreButtonListener);
            ignoreButton.addSelectionListener(ignoreButtonListener);

            changeButton.removeSelectionListener(modifiedChangeButtonListener);
            changeButton.addSelectionListener(changeButtonListener);

            suggestedWords.setEnabled(true);

            wrongWord.setText(oldWrongWord);
            wrongWord.addKeyListener(new WrongWordKeyListener());

            if (suggestedWords.getItem(0).equals("No Suggestions")) {
                changeButton.setEnabled(false);
            }

        }
    }

    private static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> java.util.List<T> asSortedList(Collection<T> c) {
        java.util.List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>(c);
        java.util.Collections.sort(list);
        java.util.Collections.reverse(list);
        return list;
    }

    @Override
    protected Control createButtonBar(Composite parent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Point getInitialSize() {
        Point size = super.getInitialSize();
        size.x = 500;
        size.y = 350;
        return size;
    }
}
```

Here is SpellChecker class:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.eclipse.core.runtime.FileLocator;
import org.eclipse.epf.richtext.RichTextPlugin;
import org.osgi.framework.Bundle;

class SpellChecker {

    private final HashMap<String, Integer> nWords = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    public SpellChecker() throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
        Bundle bundle = RichTextPlugin.getDefault().getBundle();
        URL fileURL = bundle.getEntry("files/dictionary.txt");
        File file = null;
        file = new File(FileLocator.resolve(fileURL).toURI());

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w+");
        for (String temp = ""; temp != null; temp = in.readLine()) {
            Matcher m = p.matcher(temp.toLowerCase());
            while (m.find())
                nWords.put((temp = m.group()), nWords.containsKey(temp) ? nWords.get(temp) + 1 : 1);
        }
        in.close();
    }

    public boolean isInDictionary(String word){
        return nWords.containsKey(word) ? true : false;
    }

    private final ArrayList<String> edits(String word) {
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); ++i)
            result.add(word.substring(0, i) + word.substring(i + 1));
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length() - 1; ++i)
            result.add(word.substring(0, i) + word.substring(i + 1, i + 2) + word.substring(i, i + 1) + word.substring(i + 2));
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); ++i)
            for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; ++c)
                result.add(word.substring(0, i) + String.valueOf(c) + word.substring(i + 1));
        for (int i = 0; i <= word.length(); ++i)
            for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; ++c)
                result.add(word.substring(0, i) + String.valueOf(c) + word.substring(i));
        return result;
    }

    public final String correct(String word) {
        if (nWords.containsKey(word))
            return word;
        ArrayList<String> list = edits(word);
        HashMap<Integer, String> candidates = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        for (String s : list)
            if (nWords.containsKey(s))
                candidates.put(nWords.get(s), s);
        if (candidates.size() > 0)
            return candidates.get(Collections.max(candidates.keySet()));
        for (String s : list)
            for (String w : edits(s))
                if (nWords.containsKey(w))
                    candidates.put(nWords.get(w), w);
        return candidates.size() > 0 ? candidates.get(Collections.max(candidates.keySet())) : word;
    }

    public final HashMap<Integer, String> suggestions(String word) {
        if (nWords.containsKey(word)) {
            HashMap<Integer, String> wordMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
            wordMap.put(1, word);
            return wordMap;
        }
        ArrayList<String> list = edits(word);
        HashMap<Integer, String> candidates = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        for (String s : list)
            if (nWords.containsKey(s))
                candidates.put(nWords.get(s), s);
        if (candidates.size() > 0)
            return candidates;
        for (String s : list)
            for (String w : edits(s))
                if (nWords.containsKey(w))
                    candidates.put(nWords.get(w), w);
        return candidates;
    }

}
```